# Was there an opposing group in "Interface?"

Tags: neal-stephenson, interface

Near the beginning of the novel *Interface*, we learn of an organization (actually a business coalition) called "The Network" that acts as a driving force behind the plot of the novel. It's briefly mentioned that there were other, similar organizations like "The Network".

Were any of those other groups involved in the events that led to the conclusion of the novel, or was all of that really random circumstance? If other groups were involved, which ones?